# Dynamic referencing to worksheet

Tags: excel

Let's say I have many worksheets: `Total, Product1, Product2,... Product100`. All the `Productx` worksheets are identical in the distribution of cells.

I would like to collect in worksheet `Total` the cell values from all the product worksheets. 
I can get the value of cell `D12` in worksheet `Product15` by clicking [I would get in the cell `='Product15'!D12`]. I can drag that and get the following `='Product15'!D13`, `='Product15'!D14` which is great!

However, is there any way to avoid clicking and do it automatically? (I have many Product tables!).

I tried putting all the Product worksheet names in a row, and create an indirect link but it didn't work. Ex. where "Product15" would be in the `Total` worksheet and in cell `B$15`:

```
=indirect(concatenate("'",B$15,"'!",D13),TRUE)
```

Any idea/comment hugely appreciated!

[image: Example not working]

Comment: You also want `D13` to update to `D14`, etc. when you drag down?

Comment: If there were an Item3 below, then when I drag I should pick Product1,D14 cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sheet *Total* cell **A1** enter:

```
=INDIRECT("Product" & ROW() & "!D12")
```

and copy down.

Answer (score 1):

you could make the D in D13 a string but the 13 a number which is recalculated when copied:

```
=indirect(concatenate("'",D$3,"'!","D", ROW()+8),TRUE)
```

with `8` adjusted as needed